# how to display popup to disable the search button while fetching/requesting data from the web server using Pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have this page:

```
<div>
    <label id="lblchecked"></label>
    <input id="ipt_search" type="search" title="Search" />
    <button id="btn_search" onclick="loadXMLDoc();"> Search</button>
</div>
<div id="response">
    <table id="tbl"></table>
</div>    

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog" style="display:none;">
    <div>
        <h2>Please wait .......... </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

In .js file I fetch data from server as:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    document.getElementById("openModal").style.display = "block";
    var Searchtxt=   document.getElementById("ipt_search").value;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            myFunction(myArr);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://test.com/"+Searchtxt, true);

    xhttp.send();
}
```

I want to make the `openModel` pop up appear while it is fetching the server data and close it again after the data has loaded.

In vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: It looks like your code makes the modal appear - do you just need to know where to put the code to make it disappear again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to modify our `onreadystatechange` event handler slightly to hide your `modalDialog` div once the ajax request completes.

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var openModal = document.getElementById("openModal")
    var Searchtxt = document.getElementById("ipt_search").value;

    // show modal
    openModal.style.display = "block";

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState === 4) {

            // http request completed

            if (xhttp.status === 200) {

                // successful

                var myArr = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                myFunction(myArr);
            }

            // hide modal, successful or not

            openModal.style.display = 'none';
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "https://test.com/"+Searchtxt, true);
    xhttp.send();
};
```

This example will close the `modalDialog` after the request completes, but only calls `myFunction()` if the request was successful.